# How to compare two expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Suppose the random variables X and Y follow an unknown joint distribution, and we do not know the independence of X and Y.

If I want to prove, let's assume $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ < $\mathbb{E}[XY^2]$, is it equivalent to prove by taking the conditional expectation that: for $\forall x \in X(w): \mathbb{E}[XY | X=x] < \mathbb{E}[XY^2|X=x]$?

If the latter one can prove the former one, is the latter one necessary?

Comment: It is certainly not necessary: consider $Y=X$ with probability $1$ and $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$

Comment: yeah, but can I prove the former one by the latter one?